# "Business Days" before and after a holiday in SQL

Tags: sql, date, reporting-services

I've read through a lot of similar questions but my particular case is a little simpler and yet more complex than most other situations I've found. Here's the question:

I have a table of labor transactions with date/time stamps for users clocking in and clocking out. Each transaction (row) has a username, start and stop time, a total # of hours, and a "tag" (usually the a work order #).

For holidays, we add a transaction for each user with no start or stop time, 8 as the total # of hours and "HOLIDAY" as the tag. I've made a sample of the table below:

```
USER   | STARTDATE | STARTTIME | STOPDATE | STOPTIME | HOURS | TAG
JSMITH | 7/2/12    | 9:00AM    | 7/2/12   | 5:00PM   | 8     | WO12345
JSMITH | 7/3/12    | 9:00AM    | 7/3/12   | 5:00PM   | 8     | WO13579
JSMITH | 7/4/12    | NULL      | 7/4/12   | NULL     | 8     | HOLIDAY
JSMITH | 7/5/12    | 9:00AM    | 7/5/12   | 5:00PM   | 8     | WO24680
JSMITH | 7/6/12    | 9:00AM    | 7/6/12   | 5:00PM   | 8     | WO98765
```

Here's the issue. The user is only supposed to get the 8 hours of vacation IF he works the 2 business days prior the key word being BUSINESS days. A vacation day (which would have a tag of VACATION) would qualify as "working". So basically if there is ANY labor transaction on each of the 2 days prior, they would qualify for the holiday.

To further complicate the matter, Mon through Fri would be a typical work week, however, people are ABLE to work on Saturday (though not required) so if a holiday fell on a Monday, they could work either Thurs/Fri OR Fri/Sat to qualify for the holiday.

This report would be run once a week (on monday) and look at the previous week. So my thought process is that you look for any transaction with a tag of Holiday, the check back 2 "business" days prior for any transactions on each day. If no transaction is found for one or both days, return the user, or the full holiday row, to indicate that they do NOT qualify (final result set should be a list of transactions or users that do NOT qualify for the holiday).

Any and all help with either checking 2 previous days or determining "business" days (including possibly Saturday) would be greatly appreciated! Also let me know if you need any further detail.

Thanks!

Comment: So join the table to itself, and just query `DATEPART(weekday, startdate)`?

Comment: Is someone that works Thu,Sat eligible for the Mon holiday?

Comment: @dbenham - Thurs / Sat is not valid. Only Thurs/Fri or Fri/Sat. Fri is a required day, Saturday is not. In the case of a holiday on a Tuesday, the valid cases would be Fri/Mon or Sat/Mon

Comment: @D.R. That means my answer below won't work for you. It will happily consider Thu/Sat as valid. Maybe I'll have time to revise this later..

Comment: @D.R. Ok, I've updated the answer. This should fit the bill.

Comment: @RobertJeppesen I'll take a look at it on Weds when I'm in the office. If I have any issues, I'll update it here

Answer (score 0):

Start with this.

```
SELECT a.[STARTDATE] 'Begin Date', a.[TAG] AS 'Begin Tag', 
  b.[TAG] AS '1 Day Before', c.[TAG] AS '2 Days Before',
  d.[TAG] AS '3 Days Before',  e.[TAG] AS '4 Days Before',
  f.[TAG] AS '5 Days Before'
FROM tx a
LEFT JOIN tx b ON b.[USER] = a.[USER] 
  AND b.[STARTDATE] = DATEADD (day, -1, a.[STARTDATE])
LEFT JOIN tx c ON c.[USER] = a.[USER] 
  AND c.[STARTDATE] = DATEADD (day, -2, a.[STARTDATE])
LEFT JOIN tx d ON d.[USER] = a.[USER] 
  AND d.[STARTDATE] = DATEADD (day, -3, a.[STARTDATE])
LEFT JOIN tx e ON e.[USER] = a.[USER] 
  AND e.[STARTDATE] = DATEADD (day, -4, a.[STARTDATE])
LEFT JOIN tx f ON f.[USER] = a.[USER] 
  AND f.[STARTDATE] = DATEADD (day, -5, a.[STARTDATE])
WHERE a.[STARTDATE] = '2012-07-05'
```

This will give you the tags for the previous 5 days (by date):

```
Begin Date Begin Tag 1 Day Before 2 Days Before 3 Days Before 4 Days Before 5 Days Before
---------- --------- ------------ ------------- ------------- ------------- -------------
2012-07-05 WO98765   WO24680      HOLIDAY       WO13579       WO12345       NULL
```

You would then add logic to check if the previous two days are non-holiday work tags.

Comment: My thought it that at most you would need the previous 4 days? at most 2 could be weekend days so the other 2 would have to be "business" days?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of logic gets hard to express in sql in a readable and performant way. 
Often, I find it easier to just create a facts table since there is so little data. 
This way, you can just join against this facts table. 
I didn't know what your table was called, so I just called it 'Log'.

I believe this code will do what you want.

**Update**

To allow for the restriction that Fri/Sat is allowed, but not Thu/Sat, I revised the fact table to include the allowed combinations. For each valid combination give a new row of weekday (of holiday), and two allowed offsets. 
For Mon (weekday 2 in US), give two pairs, (-2,-3) and (-3,-4), meaning Fri/Sat, and Thu/Fri, respectively.

New code:

```
-- Create a facts table. This would maybe not be a temp table in the final solution but
-- rather a static, indexed table. 

CREATE TABLE #validdays (
   forday int,
   validday1 int, -- offset from 'forday'
   validday2 int  -- offset from 'forday'
)
-- For each weekday, give the allowed combinations of work days
INSERT INTO #validdays values (2,-2,-3)
INSERT INTO #validdays values (2,-3,-4)
INSERT INTO #validdays values (6,-1,-2)
INSERT INTO #validdays values (5,-1,-2)
INSERT INTO #validdays values (4,-1,-2)
INSERT INTO #validdays values (3,-1,-3)
INSERT INTO #validdays values (3,-1,-4)

SELECT * 
FROM Log l
WHERE 
   l.TAG = 'HOLIDAY' AND
   NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT *
    FROM #validdays v 
    INNER JOIN Log vl ON vl.[USER] = l.[USER] AND 
                         vl.startdate = DATEADD(day, v.validday1, l.startdate) AND
                         vl.tag <> 'HOLIDAY'
    INNER JOIN Log vl2 ON vl2.[USER] = l.[USER] AND 
                          vl2.startdate = DATEADD(day, v.validday2, l.startdate) AND
                          vl2.tag <> 'HOLIDAY'
    WHERE v.forday = datepart(dw,l.startdate)
   )
   -- Any restrictions about periodicity, i.e. check that l.startdate is within last week.
drop table #validdays
```